# Tracking Checkin Deals

Tags: facebook-graph-api, checkin

We are considering running a contest/drawing for users who check-in to our client's business. The [Checkin Deals (PDF)](http://ads.ak.facebook.com/ads/FacebookAds/EMEA_partner_deals_businesses_EN.pdf) feature looks really cool but it doesn't seem like you can programmatically access data on users who have checked in for a deal.

You can however get access to Checkins in general, using the Graph API. So I guess I just want to confirm that it would be possible for us to run a drawing/contest for users who check in to a place, before talking about it with our client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get information about who checked into a deal or checked into a place.  The only information like this available via the Graph API is places an individual user has checked in, if they granted your application access to read that.  It's similar to how Facebook doesn't provide who likes a page via the API, mainly due to privacy.

Comment: So we can track who checks into our place/page, so long as the user grants permission? And once permission is granted, we can query for checkins at any time, right? Thanks for the help!